# AWS Server setup with JIRA, Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, jira

I have an Amazon EC2 instance that I'd like to use as a development server for client projects as well as run JIRA. I have a domain pointed to the EC2 server IP. I'm new to docker so unsure if my approach is correct.

I'd like to have a JIRA container installed (with another jiradb MYSQL container) running at jira.domain.com as well as the potential to host client staging websites at client.domain.com which point to the client's docker containers.

I've been trying to use [This JIRA docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira/) using the provided command

```
docker run --detach --publish 8080:8080 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest
```

but the container always stops running mid setup (set up takes a while in-between steps). When I run the container again it goes back to the start of setup.

Once I have JIRA set up how would I run it under a subdomain? And how could I then have client.domain.com point to a separate docker container?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know there's two considerations for getting Jira setup, whether as server or container:

1. You need to enter a license key early in the setup process (and it requires an Internet connection for verification), even if it's an evaluation
2. By default Jira will use its built-in (H2, IIRC) database, unless you configure an external one

So, in the case of 2) you probably want to make sure you have your external database ready and set up.

See [Connecting Jira applications to external databases](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/connecting-jira-applications-to-a-database-802592175.html) for preparatory steps for a variety of databases.

You didn't mention at what stage your first setup run fails, however once you've gotten past step 1) or any further successful setup, one of the first things I did, so as not to lose all work I'd done, was to commit the container!

```
docker commit -a 'My Name' -m 'Jira configured and set up' <container ID> myrepo/myjira:mytag
```

That way you don't lose all your previous work and you save your container into a new image in one fell swoop.